# My application crash when i tracing on E they can not go to next activity

Tags: java, android, xml

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw Letter
         canvas.drawBitmap(letterBitmap, letterRect, viewRect, mPaint);
        if (needInstruct) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(traceBitmap, letterRect, viewRect, mPaint);
        } else {
            // draw points along path
            canvas.drawPoints(pathPoints, pointPaint);
        }
        // draw all finished paths
        for (Path item : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(item, processingPaint);
        }
        // draw the current unfinished path
        if (currentDrawingPath != null) canvas.drawPath(currentDrawingPath, processingPaint);
        // draw anchor
        scaleRect.set(
                anchorPos.x - anchorBitmap.getWidth() * anchorScale / 2,
                anchorPos.y - anchorBitmap.getHeight() * anchorScale / 2,
                anchorPos.x + anchorBitmap.getWidth() * anchorScale / 2,
                anchorPos.y + anchorBitmap.getHeight() * anchorScale / 2);
      //  canvas.drawBitmap(anchorBitmap, anchorRect, scaleRect, mPaint);
    }
```

the errors Show is

```
2021-10-13 10:19:56.569 1189-2679/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-10-13 10:19:56.670 1189-2679/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-10-13 10:19:56.847 18938-18938/com.example.tracingsample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tracingsample, PID: 18938
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
        at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:65)
        at android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(RecordingCanvas.java:277)
        at android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:114)
        at com.danny_jiang.tracinglibrary.view.TracingLetterView.onDraw(TracingLetterView.java:213)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21571)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20414)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20405)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20405)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20405)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20405)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20405)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4234)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21578)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:810)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20414)
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object`  see line TracingLetterView.java:213 ?